# How to remove individuals with less than n occurences in each month?

Tags: r, filter, group-by, point

I have a data.frame with species occurences (TD_threshold). This occurences are divided into different individual and different month. My goal is to select the individuals, which have more than 40 occurences per month in each month. When applying the following code, individuals which no occurences in some month but more than 40 in others remain.

```
set.seed(28)

TD_samples <-
  TD_threshold %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  group_by(ind_id, month) %>%
  sample_n(40)

head(TD_threshold)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   ind_id, month [1]
  time                ind_id month      lng      lat
  <dttm>              <fct>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2015-01-01 09:40:23 BAV3       1 -588886. 1373720.
2 2015-01-01 10:40:06 BAV3       1 -618226. 1372848.
3 2015-01-01 12:00:06 BAV3       1 -655789. 1353752.
4 2015-01-01 13:30:06 BAV3       1 -701669. 1349417.
5 2015-01-01 15:00:06 BAV3       1 -727293. 1335201.
6 2015-01-02 10:40:06 BAV3       1 -726753. 1334190.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution -

```
library(dplyr)

TD_threshold %>%
  mutate(year_month = format(time, '%Y-%m')) %>%
  add_count(ind_id, year_month) %>%
  group_by(ind_id) %>%
  filter(all(n > 40)) %>%
  ungroup
```